# Shift sign $y=\frac x{|x|}$ function horizontally

Tags: graphing-functions

I know how to shift linear and quadratic functions but is there a way to shift a sign or $$y=\frac x{|x|}$$ function?

Comment: One can in general shift $y=f(x)$. See for instance this note: https://www.math.utah.edu/~giessing/notes/ch3.6b.pdf and also https://math.berkeley.edu/~qiuyi/m1af14/EER4_Notes.pdf

Comment: Do you mean something different from simply replacing every $x$ in the expression by $x-c$ for some $c$ being the distance you want to shift the graph?

Comment: No, I didn't mean anything else. Thank you for the resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hint:

To shift any function $f$ horizontally, all you need to do is to replace $x$ by $x\pm c$ where c is the distance of the shift and the sign $\pm$ indicates the direction of the shift.

Comment: Yes, you are right. After a lot of fiddling, it turned out I misplaced parentheses when graphing the absolute value.